# Input with image type in Kohana2

Tags: html, input, kohana, kohana-2

How to make correct the input tag with image type in Kohana2? I need to make a graphical submit button in my form. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult, have you read the docs? http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/form#input